# Getting input from an Editext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to get input from an `EditText` field in `Android` and use it in another method but nothing happens. I am not certain if the error is in the `getInput` or the method that calls it.
here are the methods :

```
public String getUserInput() {
    EditText userInput = findViewById(R.id.inputAnswer);
    return userInput.getText().toString();
}

public void checkQuestion3() {
    String name = getUserInput();
    if (name.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Class")) {
        score += 1;
    }
}
```

and the edittext at xml:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputAnswer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Your Answer"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLength="15" />
```

Comment: And where do you call `checkQuestion3()`?

Comment: This is the part i am not sure off. I don't think it is possible to call the method on the text field but i need score to increment once the user checks done

Comment: Can you tell me what is your output? Do you want to set a dialog with edittext than display the value or do you want to change it whenever you are typing or what exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a listener or some sort of button to call the method.

```
userInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // you can call or do what you want with your EditText here
        // yourEditText... 
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
});
```

Comment: Thanks, ii will try this.